# Where can I find google-play-services_lib.jar?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I was following [this tutorial](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435) to achieve support for Google Maps V2 on Android. Unfortunately during second step I didn't select copy to workspace option and I deleted project with `\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib` directory. After that I have noticed that I remove `google-play-services_lib.jar`, but it still was present in SDK. I have deleted Google Play Services and installed them again, but still there is no `google-play-services_lib.jar`. What should I do?

Comment: its a library project and you to reference the same. you need to follow http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: By "library project" he means "not a jar", you have to load it like a project, not a library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Donwload it from the SDK Manager and then go to the folder 
"\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib"

Comment: Donwload it from the SDK Manager and then go to the folder "\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib", copy this folder into your workspace. and use it in your project as reference library.Right click on project name properties=>Android=>Is Library section's Add button.

Comment: where is the sdk folder?

Comment: There is no sub-directory named `libproject` under **google_play_services**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982533/how-to-download-older-google-play-services

Answer (score 0):

Visit this site and download google play service https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs

Comment: Is that the same as **google_play_services** lib?  Seems like just the client libraries...