# NullPointerException since changing Google Maps API key

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an error in my Android application. The application worked perfectly and then when I was building the apk I realised my Google Maps API key wasn't going to work for multiple users, so I made a new one following the Google tutorial. Now when I install my app I get a force close - could someone help me ?

This is the logcat:

```
`03-20 15:42:45.209    3906-3906/project.sharethefare E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: project.sharethefare, PID: 3906
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{project.sharethefare/project.sharethefare.CurrentLocation}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at project.sharethefare.CurrentLocation.setUpMapIfNeeded(CurrentLocation.java:55)
            at project.sharethefare.CurrentLocation.onCreate(CurrentLocation.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
`
```

This is the class:

```
    public class CurrentLocation extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    //________________________________________________________________________________________

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        //auto generated
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_location);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();                                     //part of google maps api
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);                               //creates a new HomeScreen
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {                             //Auto Generated
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();                                 //set up map if not already created
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.curLocMap))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    //call the method to continuously check current location
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
    }

    //called above. Used to constantly update the users position on the map
    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            //create a new latitude and longitude point
            LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            //make global variables on home screen == to current location
            HomeScreen.curLat = location.getLatitude();
            HomeScreen.curLong = location.getLongitude();
            HomeScreen.curLocSet = true;
            //animate the camera to zoom in on position when found
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
        }
    };

    public void backToHome(View view){ // called when button clicked. returns to homeScreen activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentLocation.this,HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your `...findFragmentById(R.id.curLocMap)` can't find the view you are looking for. As a result `null` is returned which later used to call `getMap()`, ending with a `NullPointerException`. Check the `id` is correct, and the view exists in your layout file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653898/google-maps-fragment-returning-null-inside-a-fragment. Note the second answer (with 4 points -- not the accepted one).