# Can't load map in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I am using google map in my app. I can able to load map with positions except Lollipop version mobiles.
But in Lollipop version map is not loaded 
Here I have taken the logs and it's showing like this

> 05-14 20:33:35.078: W/System.err(988): java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke
>
> virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
>
> com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object
>   reference
>
> MTK_CheckAppName:68: appName=com.appname.android,
>   acAppName=com.android.gallery3d

I am getting this type of log only when loading in Lollipop versions.
So this problem occurs only in Android 5.0 version not in below versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Fragment returning null inside a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653898/google-maps-fragment-returning-null-inside-a-fragment)

Comment: @CHRIS : AM only getting @ lolipop versions

Comment: which version of play services are you using on the devices you test?
The newest versions of the API requires to use Async retrieve of GoogleMap object