# Google map called inside a fragment returns null

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to put Map inside a fragment. 
I am pasting the codes I am using

XML

```
           <fragment
            android:id="@+id/contactFrag_F_map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

Below is my Fragment name declared

```
public class ContactFragment extends MapFragment
```

Below is how I initialised map

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {

        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();
        }
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this method was called on `onCreateView`

The error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

Please help to solve this issue. The issue is in below portion

```
if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();
            }
```

**EDIT 1**

Changed the xml to

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/contactFrag_F_map" 
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

and

```
public class ContactFragment extends SupportMapFragment
```

And the initialisation

```
if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();
            }
```

But again the error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

and it happens in the line

```
if (googleMap == null) {
                    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                            R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();
                }
```

Why would this happen??

**EDIT 2**

Yes.. the getmap is deprecated . So i tried

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contactFrag_F_map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and ..

```
public class ContactFragment extends MapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

and the callback ..

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        theGoogleMap = googleMap;

        setUpMap();
    }
```

and the setUpMap method

```
public void setUpMap(){

        theGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        theGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
```

And the error is showing in onresume()

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.purpletab.daga/com.purpletab.daga.activities.CoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference
```

also

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fl.o()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: pls try `getSupportFragmentmanager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653898/google-maps-fragment-returning-null-inside-a-fragment

Comment: @Ruben Please see the comment on IntelliJ Amiya 's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution.
I was placing a **Map Fragment inside a Fragment**.

So....

xml to be placed inside the fragment is

```
 <fragment
                android:id="@+id/contactFrag_F_map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

and ..

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

with in `onCreateView()`

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contactFrag_F_map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

And on OnMapReadyCallback

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        theGoogleMap = googleMap;

        setUpMap();
    }
```

and below is the setUpMap.

```
public void setUpMap(){

        theGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        theGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        theGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
```

works fine.. :)

Comment: I am having this problem, but I cannot easily convert from SupportMapFragment to MapFragment. Do you think if I make the conversion to MapFragment it will work?

Answer (score 5):

**<s>Don't</s>**

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();
```

**Do**

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentmanager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();
```

**getSupportFragmentManager**

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this activity.

Comment: I am using an activity that extends AppCompact activity.   
The fragment extends MapFragment.   

So it gives error when i try 
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentmanager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.contactFrag_F_map)).getMap();

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager/26890034#26890034

Answer (score 1):

try to use below code :

```
private void initilizeMap() {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.contactFrag_F_map);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    }
    mapView = fragment.getMap();
}
```

In Your Xml file:

```
       <fragment
            android:id="@+id/contactFrag_F_map" 
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
             />
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreateView

```
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMap = mMapView.getMap();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

in xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/tag_text_header" />
```

Comment: i am using 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

Comment: yeah i am using the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're doing it all wrong from the beginning - see [getMap](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMap()):

> This method is deprecated. Use getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) instead. The callback method provides you with a GoogleMap instance guaranteed to be non-null and ready to be used.

Second - it seems (however I'm not sure) you are not familiar with fragments nesting, read this [NestedFragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).