# Google API client on watch emulator

Tags: android, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to write an application for android watch. As following some of the samples available in Android SDK I wrote a service in android watch project which uses the `GoogleApiClient`. But as soon as it try to connect to `GoogleApiClient`, connection gets failed with the error `"service_version_update_required"`

Apparently there seems to be no Google Play APK on watch emulator, so even if I follow the `GoolgeApiClient` documentation for error handling this does not update the Google Play apk.

Is there a workaround to this problem or do I have to buy the actual hardware watch?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using Eclipse (not sure if this is a problem on Android Studio), the only solution I found was to use an older version of the Google Play Services library in my Wear project.

The latest version of the library (as of today, it's 7095000) does not work with the emulator you can create using Eclipse. So I reverted to an older version I had (version 6587000) and the `GoogleApiClient` now connects just fine.

If you don't have an older version, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838281/362298) which links to several earlier versions. The latest you can get there is version 6171000 ([download link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_6171000_r21.zip)). It's slightly older than the one I have but it should work.