# Google plus sign in without hitting the dex Limit

Tags: android, google-play-services

How can I use google plus sign in without my app reaching 65K methods?

Can I try with some earlier version of google play services? If yes, a link to guide for that would be awesome.

It feels really lame to include such a big library for just the google plus sign in.

Has anyone managed to use google play services 7.8 without reaching the dex limit?

Comment: all you have to do is include `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'`

Comment: @tyczj ironically this wasn't mention in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can selectively include only the needed services.

> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google
>   Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your
>   build.gradle file:
>
> `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'` with these lines:
>
> `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.8.0'`
>   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0'`

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) about details and what to use for the various services.

Comment: Awesome answer, I didn't know you can do that! @vedant1811 but yes, you can also use older version of google play services - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26838281/1182260

Comment: Do not use old versions of the play services. The new versions don't only provide new functions but also bug fixes and security fixes.