# Project ActionBar Error After Google Play Service Update

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have the following error after updating Google Play Services:

```
[2015-12-19 10:58:19 - google-play-services_lib] C:\Tools\Android\sdk_24\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v11\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
[2015-12-19 10:58:19 - google-play-services_lib] C:\Tools\Android\sdk_24\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

I had already imported appcompat_v7. Everything was working fine before the google play service import.

Comment: can u please share your app level build.gradel file

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, only that I have found in google code groups was to move to old lib version

Comment: I didn't make a backup and use SDK manager, did you manually download the older version?

Answer (score 0):

- Ok I downloaded an older version of Google Play Services as per this answer:
  [How to download older google play services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982533/how-to-download-older-google-play-services)
- Removed my updated version (from eclipse and disk)
- Imported r27 release into Eclipse

No more updating anything again!

Comment: not a good choice to permanently avoid updating libraries. This will get fixed and you should keep trying once in a while and see if it has been. Otherwise you will miss out on other important enhancements.