# Google play service resource not found

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have update SDK using SDK manger,after updating SDK "google-play-services_lib" not getting complied,Its showing following error.

```
**extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v11\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.

extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.

 extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v11\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.

 extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.**
```

Any Help appreciated.

Following is xml(under "values-v11") which is giving error,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base preview application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppInvite.Preview.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: As per my understanding your project(s) are not getting. [I think it will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Comment: are you using eclipse or android studio. ?

Comment: I had exact same problem.
This answer helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34451936/1626106

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This may fix your problem

1. Right side click on your project select *Properties* -> Select *Android*
2. Under *Project Build Target*, check *Android 6.0 or to the latest API.
3. Build

***One important thing : While importing library projects always copy to your workspace.***

**UPDATED:** 
**Reason :** Most of time ***google play service lib*** access resources from lastest API available. that's why you need to target to the latest.

Comment: Thanks Bharat ,I tried what you mentioned in your answer still not working.. I am having issue in "google-play-services_lib"(library) after updating SDK..its library problem but unfortunately I could not figure out fix.

Comment: Ok then do this select Android 6.0. if 6.0 SDK is not there install the same.  then clean and build the project.

Comment: its working after changing android 6.0..Could you please explain what went wrong after taking SDK update and why its working after changing android version library and project to 6.0....Thanks

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer as it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution it worked for me (after a few hours):

1) Unistall the Google Play Services Lib from "Android SDK Manager". It will ask you if you want to delete also the directory in your workspace. Answer "Yes"

2) Download again the Google Play Library from the "Android SDK Manager" and follow the steps to import it to your workspace

3) Set Android Target for google-play-services-lib for 5.0.1 (these are the versions for me worked)

4) In the project you want to import, right click->properties->Android . Add again the google-play-services-lib library.

5) Set Android Target for your project to 5.0.1 (the same case that point 3: I guess it can work for other versions)

6) Only in case the above solution will not work, copy the android-support-v4.jar from <...>/sdk/extras/android/support/v4 to the "libs" folder of your project.

I hope it works for you

Comment: this reason is updated google service with no install android 6.x problem

Answer (score 1):

For the new Google Play Services, you need change the project target in the `project.properties` file (The Google Play Services Lib project, not your project):

> In the below file:

`google-play-services_lib/project.properties`

> Change the below line

```
target=**android-9*
```

> to:

```
target=**android-23**
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to compile your project with the `android target-sdk-version="21"`.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I am adding "google-play-services_lib" to my project library it self is not compiling..how can I compile my project.Its problem with library.

Comment: @Joe is possible to attach screenshot of your setup

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the `minSdkVersion` in `google-play-services_lib` manifest to the minimum SDK version used by my app. Example: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>`