# Google Play Services no lib found?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I want to use the Google Play Services for my android app in order to use google place API but on https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
I must find `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/` but I don't find that when I download with androidSDK.

Also I read that I had to download m2repository too but I don't find the lib too...

The thing I have in this dirctory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\10.2.6`)
is this file play-services-10.2.6.aar

Can someone explain me what should I do please ? ( I'm using netbeans 7.4 )

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310684/missing-sdk-extras-google-google-play-services-libproject-folder-after-updat

Comment: i follow all the step here : ("Here are the steps: 1. Rename .aar to .zip 2. Unzip the file 3. Create a 'libs' folder and move the classes.jar file into it 4. Import the project into Eclipse by using New -> Project -> Android Project from Existing Source Code 5. Go to the Project's properties and set the Build Target and 'Is Library' flag " ) i don't have the classes.jar when i extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check [highlights from the Google Play services 10.2 release](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_version_102) wherein it was stated that it no longer includes full support for Android version 2.3.x.

> Apps developed using SDK release 10.2.x and later require a minimum Android API level of 14 and cannot be installed on devices running an API level below 14.

If you haven't done so, try to add this in your Android manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

You may want to check [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#manifest) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631562/google-play-service-resource-not-found/34632322) for more information.