# Error in xml file after updating google play services

Tags: android, eclipse, attributes

I updated my google play services (rev 29)but its showing error in the xml files.

```
  Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.

  [2016-01-22 12:24:42 - google-play-services_lib]
  C:\Users\Gaurav\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: 
  error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name    '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
  [2016-01-22 12:24:42 - google-play-services_lib]
```

Thank you beforehand

Here is my xml file of AppInvite.xml(v21)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
   <!-- Base preview application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppInvite.Preview.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

the particular theme has been implemented but in the parent attribute its showing error. **What next?**

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to use a specific style: `Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar` which is not implemented yet.

To implement this style, go to : *res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml* and add it here

Hope it helps

Comment: m trying to implement but its showing error in the appinvite_styles.xml

Comment: It's what I said: you have to add this style to your appinvite_styles.xml

Comment: i have shared the xml file can u plz check it once and suggest me the further step to remove the error.Thanku in advance

Comment: Create this theme: Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar in your appinvite_styles.xml. Or follow the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34451936/5778152